# Android Studio Out of Memory Error

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
I keep getting out of memory error as can be seen on screenshot. I'm developing on Mac(2.9Ghz i7) and using Android Studio v0.8.9. I closed all running programs, restarted computer increased xmx,and xx values but nothing works.

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: What do you do that causes the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Nothing. I was just working as i used to and doing nothing speacial. Suddenly it started giving this error for all projects i open

Comment: Even if you weren't doing anything out of the ordinary or special, you still had to be doing **something** before you got this error.